# Mostrar arreglo con espacios entre cada dato diferente

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Hola comienzo en el mundo de la programación y aun tengo bastantes problemas al hacer algunos procesos, por lo cual solicito de su ayuda.
Problema: Estoy leyendo un arreglo con jquery que trae claves de algunos proveedores y quisiera separar las claves de cada proveedor por un salto de linea (ejemplo arreglo)

```
array = ['proveedor1', 'proveedor1', 'proveedor2', 'proveedor3', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4','proveedor4', 'proveedor5'];
```

quisiera que mostraran de esta manera al imprimir los datos

```html
proveedor1
proveedor1
//espacio
proveedor2
//espacio
proveedor3 
//espacio
proveedor4
proveedor4
proveedor4
//espacio
proveedor5
```

Como pueden ver solo necesito hacer un salto de linea cada que el proveedor sea diferente

```html
array = ['proveedor1', 'proveedor1', 'proveedor2', 'proveedor3', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4','proveedor4', 'proveedor5'];

let Clave = '';
array.forEach((item) => {   
  clave = item.proveedor;
  if(clave == item.proveedor){
    console.log(item.proveedor);
  }
  else{
       console.log("\n");
  }

});
```

Realice el código anterior pero no me lo hace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo almacenando el valor anterior en una variable auxiliar, en caso de que el valor actual sea distinto del anterior (y siempre que el valor anterior exista) añades un salto de línea:

```js
array = ['proveedor1', 'proveedor1', 'proveedor2', 'proveedor3', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor5'];

let anterior = '';
let linea = '';
array.forEach((item) => {
  linea = item;
  if (anterior != linea && anterior != '') {
    console.log("\n");
  }
  anterior = linea;
  
  console.log(linea);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro me ayudo bastante tu código exactamente lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 5):

Supongo que lo que buscas es más bien esto:

```js
array = ['proveedor1', 'proveedor1', 'proveedor2', 'proveedor3', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor4', 'proveedor5'];

array.forEach((item) => {
  if (typeof (clave_anterior) === "undefined" || clave_anterior == item) {
    console.log(item);
  } else {
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(item);
  }
  clave_anterior = item
});
```

**Explicación**

Dentro del bucle, en el condicional, compruebo si la variable **clave_anterior** no está definida mediante el uso del operador [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), con el propósito de saber si es el primer ciclo del bucle y evitar crear una línea en blanco al no cumplirse la siguiente condición:

```javascript
typeof (clave_anterior) === "undefined"
```

o bien (mediante el uso del operador `||`), si lo está, compruebo si equivale al valor iterado (`item`) en este ciclo del array:

```javascript
clave_anterior == item
```

y si se cumple cualquiera de esas dos condiciones agrego a la salida de la consola el valor iterado del array, y si no lo es le agrego un salto de linea y despues el nuevo valor.

Finalmente establezco la variable **clave_anterior** con el valor iterado actual para el siguiente ciclo.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro me ayudo bastante tu código exactamente lo que necesitaba e incluso bastante escalable para otros problemitas que tenia, Muchas gracias bro

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, ahora es un poco más compleja, pero necesaria para evitar que tengas que saber siempre cual es el primer elemento del array que vas a usar en el forEach.